# Insert a query as a job using javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I want to insert a query as a job using the [insert](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) API method. I want to use the javascript API and I don't seem to get any examples for the same. When I tried passing in just a query like so:

```
function insertQueryAsJob() {
  var request = ggapi.client.bigquery.jobs.insert({
      'projectId':project_id,
      'query': 'SELECT * FROM [test.test] LIMIT 10'
      });
  request.execute(function(response) {     
      $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(response, null));
      });
}
```

I got an error as below:

```
Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object
(e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0
```

Google does not have documentation on the Javascript usage. Can someone please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#OptionLoadtheserviceAPIthenassembletherequest) provides the details of how to invoke the Javascript API. Based on this, the 'body' parameter should be sent as a 'resource' property. So:

```
  var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.insert({
      'projectId':project_id,
      resource:{
        'configuration': {
          'query': {
            'query': 'SELECT * FROM [test.test] LIMIT 10'
          }
      }
  }});
```

works alright.

Answer (score 1):

I still need to try this with Javascript, but have a language independent answer in the meantime:

Take a look at the reference for jobs.insert at https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert, and the examples at https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data.

The question above tries to insert:

```
{
  'projectId':project_id,
  'query': 'SELECT * FROM [test.test] LIMIT 10'
}
```

Problem is jobs.insert doesn't take a 'query', but a body with a job configuration:

```
body = {
  'configuration': {
    'query': {
      'query': 'SELECT * FROM [test.test] LIMIT 10'
    }
  }
}
```

Now with a well formed body, with a job configuration:

```
ggapi.client.bigquery.jobs.insert(
  projectId=project_id,
  body=body
);
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer, but this too doesn't work in Javascript. Please see my answer below (I made another attempt based on your answer) for the right config.